# How to navigate to a shortcut in terminal[OSX]?

Tags: macos, terminal

I want to know if its possible to navigate to a shortcut in the terminal.

A quick example:

```
cd documents/websites
```

Now i am in the right directory with the shortcut.

*I named the shortcut xampp*

Now if i type: *cd xampp*, the next error appears:

```
-bash: cd: xampp: Not a directory
```

I know the option link (ln), but i think it is to much work for every shortcut.

So is there a nice and quick solution?

Comment: How do you create the shortcut?

Comment: Just created an Alias

Comment: Commands like `cd` don't know about Alias files, so they can't resolve them. They can resolve symbolic links.